# How to let git status print only folder name for staged new folders?

Tags: git, git-status

In git, if a new folder is not staged, `git status` will only print folder name as following:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        new-folder/
```

But once it was staged, `git status` will print the new folder this way:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   new-folder/new-file-1
        new file:   new-folder/new-file-2
        new file:   new-folder/new-file-3
        new file:   new-folder/new-file-4
        ...
        new file:   new-folder/new-file-199
        new file:   new-folder/new-file-200
```

It there a way to get a list of staged changes but only folder names for staged new folders?

I'm writing a script to get a list of modified/added/deleted files before commit, by means of `git status --porcelain`. In the above case, the list will be too long.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-status%5D+directory

Answer (score 0):

```
git diff-tree @ `git write-tree`
```

is a pretty good starting point, with whatever formatting options you want like name-status and diff-filter.